# Adding character at the end of float(input)

Tags: python

I’m making a simple percentage calculator & I’m currently stuck not knowing how to add “%” at the end of `float(input)`. I want the terminal to say

```
“What is (number input) %

“of:”
```

I haven’t added the code to format the percentage properly, I’m just worried about adding the “%” right now

```
def percentIs(percentNum, num):
    percent = percentNum * num
    
    return str(percent) + str("%")

percentNum = float(input("What is" + " "))
num = float(input("of:" + " "))

print(percentIs(percentNum,num))
```

Comment: You want the text that they input to be between the text that you display in the terminal? That is, you want the blinking cursor line to be 'mid-sentence'? that might be a bit much for the input() function. But I imagine that your final web-app won't have a terminal displayed inside of it, and so there would be a different way to accomplish this in the app itself?

Comment: Yes that is correct. Any suggestions on alternatives to input()?

Comment: This is a _console_ application, not a web-app. If an HTML input form is what you want, `input()` is not correct. And no, characters cannot be placed after what is being typed on the console unless you want to use something like `curses` module

Comment: You CAN say `num = input("Enter value:    %\rEnter value:")`.  That displays the % in the right spot, but as soon as they start typing, it will disappear.

Comment: @OneCricketeer That is what I’m trying to do I suppose… a webpage in HTML that has an interactive Python program in it, I guess I just don’t know the difference, thank you though.

Comment: You'd use Javascript, then. Websites cannot run Python